# Upgrading from PHP 5.6 to 7.3, $_COOKIE['myusername'] is not working

Tags: php, php-7.3

Upgrading to PHP 7.3 from 5.6, and this line of code is causing my webpage not to load:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '".$_COOKIE['myusername']."'";
```

THE PAGE LOADS when I replace the `'".$_COOKIE['myusername']."'`  with `'name@gmail.com'`.

BUT I NEED THE COOKIE in the SQL Query

Blank Page when `'".$_COOKIE['myusername']."'` is used.

Page loads when email in database `'name@gmail.com'` is used

Blank Page when email that is not in database is used.

Apparently `'".$_COOKIE['myusername']."' is the old way to type a cookie into sql query. anyone know the new way in php7.3?

Comment: are you sure that the select gives an result besides an error. Further enter an error handling in your code

Comment: Be sure you have what you expect in $_COOKIE with an echo-Statement.
To locate errors add:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
(Don't forget to remove it in production-environment)

Comment: SQL injection will cause you serious issues if there's a `'` in the cookie.